# Is this processor burned?

Tags: intel-pentium, hyper-threading, lga775

I've recently exchange the processors in two PCChips boards. Both boards are LGA775. Board A is P17G(Pentium 4 HyperThreading 3GHz) and board B is P49G(Pentium Dual Core 3GHz). I use board A to watch videos, and some of them are 3GB size and this is why I exchanged the CPU. I installed Dual Core in board A and it worked out of the box, now 3GB videos use 5% of CPU instead of 50%.

When I installed the pentium in the board B, I forgot to connect the 4pin power and, when i powered on the PC, the CPU fan stay off. Then, I connected all right this time, and now the board doesnt show video. I think the CPU is not working but im not sure about that. The PC turns on and the HD spins, the CPU fan spins, network socket blinking,  but not video and case power led is neither blinking. I tried with other PSU and everything was the same. I figure out that CPU have that paste above. IDK really what's happening, I hope I dont have to buy another CPU.

Is it Burned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the [P49G supports Pentium 4 processors](http://www.pcchipsusa.com/PCCWebSite/Products/ProductsDetail.aspx?detailid=416&CategoryID=1&DetailName=Specification&MenuID=44&LanID=0) even though it is the same socket.

[image]

Comment: You were right i had to restore all again and worked. I thought is just about the socket. But may be p4 doesn't work with ddr3.